# Infer non-trivial OWL superclasses (or subclasses) assertions using a Java reasoner

Tags: java, owl, owl-api, description-logic, hermit

I want to express the following DL assertions in OWL

```
A ⊑ B
A ⊑ ∃R
```

meaning that `A` is subconcept of B and all the instances of `A` must have a relation `R` with something else.

I'm expressing it with the following OWL ontology:

```
Prefix(:=<http://example.org/my-ontology#>)

Ontology(<http://example.org/my-ontology>
    Declaration(Class(:A))
    Declaration(Class(:B))

    Declaration(ObjectProperty(:R))

    SubClassOf(:A :B)
    SubClassOf(:A ObjectSomeValuesFrom(:R owl:Thing))
)
```

I'm using the HermiT reasoner for retrieving all the super-classes of `:A`, in this way:

```
OWLOntology ontology = TestUtils.ontology;
OWLReasonerFactory reasonerFactory = new StructuralReasonerFactory();
ConsoleProgressMonitor progressMonitor = new ConsoleProgressMonitor();
OWLReasonerConfiguration config = new SimpleConfiguration(progressMonitor);
OWLReasoner reasoner = reasonerFactory.createReasoner(ontology, config);
reasoner.precomputeInferences();

for (OWLClass owlClass : ontology.getClassesInSignature()) {
    if (owlClass.toStringID().contains("#A")) {
        System.out.println("Class=>" + owlClass.toStringID() + "\nSuperClass[");
        System.out.println("\t" + reasoner.getSuperClasses(owlClass, false));
        System.out.println("]");
    }
}
```

but this is printing only:

```
Class=>http://example.org/my-ontology#A
SuperClass[
    Nodeset[Node( <http://example.org/my-ontology#B> ), Node( owl:Thing )]
]
```

How can I also get the information about `SubClassOf(:A ObjectSomeValuesFrom(:R owl:Thing))`?

P.S. I cannot just list the inclusion assertions from the ontology but I have to use a reasoner (not necessary HermiT) for possibly inferring them.

Comment: You're not using HermiT. The StructuralReasonerFactory class is an OWLAPI class and the reasoner it produces does not make inferences. Change that to the correct ReasonerFactory for HermiT.

Comment: @Ignazio Thank you, but even changing to `org.semanticweb.HermiT.Reasoner.ReasonerFactory` the output doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

The inferences that follow from an ontology is infinite. See [this paper](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-745/paper_22.pdf) for example.

For this reason reasoners usually limit inferences to named classes. `\exists R` is not a named class, hence it is not returned as an inference.

To get the required inference, you need to give `\exists R` a name by adding for example

`C \equiv \exists R`

The reasoner then will be able to infer `A` is a subclass of `C`.

Comment: Thank you but I cannot modify the ontology.

Comment: @user402843 Can you create a new ontology that imports the original? Without adding the definitions, you will not be able to make the desired inferences.